# Slow keyboard on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: keyboard, 19.04

I have installed Linux Ubuntu 19.04 last week on an old computer, and no problem until this morning.
When I write on the keyboard, the display time of my text is very, very,... very slow (for one phrase, I count 20-30 seconds to see my text on the screen). No character loss, all I wrote is always the same as it displays.

For now, I'm on a Microsft Wired 600 USB keyboard (but this one works normally on other computers, and no difference on the same computer if I change the connected USB slot. No difference if I use the keyboard on my computer (a Toshiba one)

Whereas, this problem doesn't appear :
- during the decryption of the hard disk (the password appears at normal speed)
- when I go on the recovery mode (I tried on the "advanced options" the option "Linux on Ubuntu 5.0" without recovery mode, no effect. Only the one with the recovery mode has a normal display speed on the text. I don't have other options in the "advanced options"
- When I lock my computer and I have to enter my password, it displays at normal speed.

I see about slow keys, but it's not activated in the accessibility features.

I also join the results of a "sudo lshw" command:

```
emeline-qosmio-x300
    description: Ordinateur Bloc-notes
    produit: Qosmio X300 (012345678912345678912345678)
    fabriquant: TOSHIBA
    version: PQX32E-055037FR
    numéro de série: 89162865K
    bits: 64 bits
    fonctionnalités: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=oem-specific chassis=notebook family=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ sku=012345678912345678912345678 uuid=5A0B84F6-6E4B-11DE-83DA-00235AFB5F54
  *-core
       description: Carte mère
       produit: KSRAA
       fabriquant: TOSHIBA
       identifiant matériel: 0
       version: 1.00
       numéro de série: 0123456789AB
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          fabriquant: TOSHIBA
          identifiant matériel: 0
          version: V2.10
          date: 03/10/2009
          taille: 116KiB
          fonctionnalités: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot acpi usb agp biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          produit: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9000  @ 2.00GHz
          fabriquant: Intel Corp.
          identifiant matériel: 4
          information bus: cpu@0
          version: CPU Version
          emplacement: U2E1
          taille: 1748MHz
          capacité: 4096MHz
          bits: 64 bits
          fonctionnalités: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm ida cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             identifiant matériel: 5
             emplacement: L1 Cache
             taille: 64KiB
             capacité: 64KiB
             fonctionnalités: asynchronous internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             identifiant matériel: 6
             emplacement: L2 Cache
             taille: 6MiB
             fonctionnalités: burst internal write-back
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: Mémoire Système
          identifiant matériel: d
          emplacement: Carte mère
          taille: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchrone 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
             identifiant matériel: 0
             emplacement: M1
             taille: 2GiB
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchrone 1066 MHz (0,9 ns)
             identifiant matériel: 1
             emplacement: M2
             taille: 2GiB
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          produit: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub
          fabriquant: Intel Corporation
          identifiant matériel: 100
          information bus: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          bits: 32 bits
          horloge: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1
             information bus: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:16 portE/S:2000(taille=4096) mémoire:cc000000-ceffffff portE/S:d0000000(taille=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                produit: G94M [GeForce 9800M GTS]
                fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                ressources: irq:26 mémoire:ce000000-ceffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff mémoire:cc000000-cdffffff portE/S:2000(taille=128) mémoire:c0000-dffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1a
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:16 portE/S:1800(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@3
                nom logique: usb3
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1a.1
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:21 portE/S:1820(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@4
                nom logique: usb4
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1a.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1a.2
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:19 portE/S:1840(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@5
                nom logique: usb5
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1a.7
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             ressources: irq:19 mémoire:f2504800-f2504bff
           *-usbhost
                produit: EHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic ehci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@1
                nom logique: usb1
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Vidéo
                   produit: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera
                   fabriquant: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
                   identifiant matériel: 6
                   information bus: usb@1:6
                   version: 3.35
                   numéro de série: SN0001
                   fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1b
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             ressources: irq:28 mémoire:f2500000-f2503fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:17 portE/S:3000(taille=4096) mémoire:f4000000-f5ffffff portE/S:f0000000(taille=33554432)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:18 portE/S:4000(taille=4096) mémoire:c0000000-c03fffff portE/S:f2000000(taille=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:0e:00.0
                nom logique: enp14s0
                version: 02
                numéro de série: 00:23:5a:fb:5f:54
                taille: 10Mbit/s
                capacité: 1Gbit/s
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                ressources: irq:18 portE/S:4000(taille=256) mémoire:f2010000-f2010fff mémoire:f2000000-f200ffff mémoire:c0000000-c000ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.3
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:19 portE/S:5000(taille=4096) mémoire:f2100000-f21fffff portE/S:c0400000(taille=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Interface réseau sans fil
                produit: WiFi Link 5100
                fabriquant: Intel Corporation
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:14:00.0
                nom logique: wlp20s0
                version: 00
                numéro de série: 00:1e:65:0f:e8:c8
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-13-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                ressources: irq:27 mémoire:f2100000-f2101fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.5
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:16 portE/S:6000(taille=4096) mémoire:f2200000-f22fffff portE/S:c0600000(taille=2097152)
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                produit: IEEE 1394 Host Controller
                fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:20:00.0
                version: 00
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=0
                ressources: irq:17 mémoire:f2200000-f22007ff mémoire:f2201000-f220107f mémoire:f2200c00-f2200c7f mémoire:f2200800-f220087f
           *-generic:0
                description: System peripheral
                produit: SD/MMC Host Controller
                fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
                identifiant matériel: 0.1
                information bus: pci@0000:20:00.1
                version: 00
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                ressources: irq:17 mémoire:f2201400-f22014ff
           *-generic:1 NON-RÉCLAMÉ
                description: SD Host controller
                produit: Standard SD Host Controller
                fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
                identifiant matériel: 0.2
                information bus: pci@0000:20:00.2
                version: 00
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                ressources: mémoire:f2201800-f22018ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                produit: MS Host Controller
                fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
                identifiant matériel: 0.3
                information bus: pci@0000:20:00.3
                version: 00
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=jmb38x_ms latency=0
                ressources: irq:17 mémoire:f2201c00-f2201cff
           *-generic:3 NON-RÉCLAMÉ
                description: System peripheral
                produit: xD Host Controller
                fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
                identifiant matériel: 0.4
                information bus: pci@0000:20:00.4
                version: 00
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                ressources: mémoire:f2202000-f22020ff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1d
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:23 portE/S:1860(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@6
                nom logique: usb6
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Souris
                   produit: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
                   identifiant matériel: 1
                   information bus: usb@6:1
                   version: 1.00
                   fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1d.1
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:19 portE/S:1880(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@7
                nom logique: usb7
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Clavier
                   produit: Wired Keyboard 600
                   fabriquant: Microsoft
                   identifiant matériel: 1
                   information bus: usb@7:1
                   version: 3.00
                   fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1d.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:18 portE/S:18a0(taille=32)
           *-usbhost
                produit: UHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic uhci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@8
                nom logique: usb8
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Interface sans fil Bluetooth
                   produit: TAIYO YUDEN for Toshiba(0x0200)
                   fabriquant: Broadcom Corp
                   identifiant matériel: 2
                   information bus: usb@8:2
                   version: 1.44
                   numéro de série: 002258EB9D71
                   fonctionnalités: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:7
             description: USB controller
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1d.7
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             ressources: irq:23 mémoire:f2504c00-f2504fff
           *-usbhost
                produit: EHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 5.0.0-13-generic ehci_hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@2
                nom logique: usb2
                version: 5.00
                fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1e
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 93
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             produit: ICH9M LPC Interface Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             ressources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             produit: 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 03
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 66MHz
             fonctionnalités: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             ressources: irq:25 portE/S:18f0(taille=8) portE/S:18e4(taille=4) portE/S:18e8(taille=8) portE/S:18e0(taille=4) portE/S:18c0(taille=32) mémoire:f2504000-f25047ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             produit: 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f.3
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 03
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             ressources: irq:19 mémoire:c0800000-c08000ff portE/S:1c00(taille=32)
     *-scsi:0
          identifiant matériel: 1
          nom logique: scsi0
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             produit: TOSHIBA MK2552GS
             fabriquant: Toshiba
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/sda
             version: 0M
             numéro de série: 49Q7CLBMT
             taille: 232GiB (250GB)
             fonctionnalités: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=bbe22d87
           *-volume:0
                description: Volume EXT4
                fabriquant: Linux
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                nom logique: /dev/sda1
                nom logique: /boot
                version: 1.0
                numéro de série: 40a506b8-b98f-40df-87df-8e567cfa2f95
                taille: 731MiB
                capacité: 731MiB
                fonctionnalités: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2019-05-07 02:14:05 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2019-05-13 14:07:18 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2019-05-13 14:07:18 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                identifiant matériel: 2
                information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                nom logique: /dev/sda2
                taille: 232GiB
                capacité: 232GiB
                fonctionnalités: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux filesystem partition
                   identifiant matériel: 5
                   nom logique: /dev/sda5
                   numéro de série: 5432065a-4f85-4307-909b-59c696c3b590
                   taille: 232GiB
                   capacité: 232GiB
                   bits: 892394360 bits
                   fonctionnalités: encrypted luks initialized
                   configuration: bits=18072263544 filesystem=luks hash=sha256 version=2
     *-scsi:1
          identifiant matériel: 2
          nom logique: scsi1
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             produit: TOSHIBA MK2552GS
             fabriquant: Toshiba
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/sdb
             version: 0M
             numéro de série: 49Q7CLBNT
             taille: 232GiB (250GB)
             fonctionnalités: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=5d379805
           *-volume
                description: Extended partition
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                nom logique: /dev/sdb1
                taille: 232GiB
                capacité: 232GiB
                fonctionnalités: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   identifiant matériel: 5
                   nom logique: /dev/sdb5
                   version: 3.1
                   numéro de série: f01afe83-d8e4-cc4d-b952-d2ba80f2d951
                   taille: 232GiB
                   capacité: 232GiB
                   fonctionnalités: ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2006-11-23 11:08:32 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
     *-scsi:2
          identifiant matériel: 3
          nom logique: scsi4
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             produit: DVDRAM GSA-T50N
             fabriquant: HL-DT-ST
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@4:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/cdrom
             nom logique: /dev/cdrw
             nom logique: /dev/dvd
             nom logique: /dev/dvdrw
             nom logique: /dev/sr0
             version: RT04
             fonctionnalités: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       produit: TOSHIBA
       fabriquant: TOSHIBA
       identifiant matériel: 1
       emplacement: Rear
       capacité: 1000mWh
       configuration: voltage=0,0V
```

Have you got an idea to fix this?

Thanks a lot, and have a good day!

PS: Sorry if I'm not so clear sometimes, I'm French and I don't have the habit to write about informatics in English.

Comment: Are you sure it is the keyboard and not a general slowness of the system? If you do something else not involving the keyboard, like clicking to open some menu or whatever, does it respond quickly then?

Comment: @Elias All is responding great, as usual. I try launch a Python program, use the mouse, launch a program with the mouse,... All other moves are as usual. It's really just the keyboard that is slow (the slowness depending on the length of the text I wrote : one letter is just one second, one phrase much more slow. And the time begins when I finish to write on the keyboard).

Comment: I tried to change my NVIDIA driver to "NVIDIA binary driver version 340.107 from nvidia-340", the legacy one, but no changes seen

Comment: I tried an other solution of migrating to Xubuntu, and it works for the moment ;)